# Starting push notifications GCM on android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to set up simple push notifications for android. But it went off right from the start. I'm following [this tutorial](http://fryerblog.com/post/30057483199/implementing-push-notifications-with-gcm) 
before I also tried by [google start up guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) 
however the problem is I can't register my app to my google service. I have enabled Google cloud Messaging. My code is:

```
   try{
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
      GCMRegistrar.register(this, "SENDER ID");
      Log.v("Registration", "new registration");// Note: get the sender id from configuration.
      regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
      Log.v("Registration", "Already registered, regId: " + regId);
    } else {             
      Log.v("Registration", "Already registered, regId: " + regId);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        String a=e.toString();
        Log.v(a,a);
    }
```

It goes on just fine but nothing really happens and after this function finishes, my app force closes. For the *sender ID*, I use the number from google.(at the end of the link).

So there seems to be no error just my app shut down after and it doesn't register. 
There is also one more funny thing. When I debug the app on my phone, it runs on, but when I start it on emulator it force closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally find a solution :d

The problem was that i named GCMIntentService wrong i named it GcmIntentService and then all went appart :S

So i post this answer if another fool like me comes into this problem...

Comment: Thanks for updating on it, I was staring at your code for ages. This is inbox/SMS vs inbox/sms for me all over again! :) Glad you got it working, mark your answer as the accepted answer so this will be closed, and of use to others in future!

Comment: I cant except it until 2 days passes, i'm glad it helps u.